# error using DATE function with HSQL

Tags: java, db2, hsqldb, ibatis

I have a project that uses SQL to access a **DB2** database. I use the a **HSQL** database when running junit test cases on the code. The java project uses SQL via iBATIS.

I experience an error if HSQL encounters the `DATE` function, for example `DATE(STATUS_CREATE_TS)` any ideas on a solution?

> --- Cause: java.sql.SQLException: user lacks privilege or object not found: DATE  at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:98)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate.execute(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:203)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate.queryForObject(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:268)

Thank you.

Comment: What is the error message saying?

Comment: --- Cause: java.sql.SQLException: user lacks privilege or object not found: DATE
 at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:98)

Answer (score 3):

This function is specific to DB2 and not supported directly by HSQLDB.

You can define the function for your tests as:

```
 create function date(ts timestamp) returns date return cast(ts as date);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Where do I define this function in HSQL?

Comment: It is an SQL statement. You execute it once. DB2 allows defining functions similarly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the HSQL setting:

```
SET DATABASE SQL SYNTAX DB2 TRUE
```

As documented in http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dbproperties-chapt.html (Table 12.27).

Comment: I believe I originally tried this approach and it didn't work. I implemented the solution proposed by fredt and it worked. Thank you.